# Should your QA Automated tests reside with application code?

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio

We currently use Visual Studio 2013 and `Silk4Test` for creating our functional and regression tests.  I am curious to know how others are storing a similar set up, meaning:

1. Should our QA Test Project be part of the overall application solution that we are testing
2. Should our QA Tests be in their own solution

Comment: See http://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=qa+code+with+application+code

Comment: It does look like a duplicate doesn't it? We'll put it on hold for now as a duplicate - @Rudesyle can you take a look at the suggestion, & if you don't think it's enough to answer your question, edit your question so it's clear what's different & we can reopen for answers.